Terraform RDS proxy subnet does not exist
I'm using the terraform module https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds-proxy/aws/2.1.2 to create an RDS proxy, like so:
module "my-rds-proxy" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds-proxy/aws"
  version = "2.1.2"
  name                   = "my-rds-proxy"
  create_iam_policy      = false
  create_iam_role        = false
  role_arn               = "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/my-role"
  vpc_subnet_ids         = ["subnet-XXXX"]
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["securitygroup-XXXX"]

  db_proxy_endpoints = {
    read_write = {
      name                   = "read-write-endpoint"
      vpc_subnet_ids         = ["subnet-XXXX"]
      vpc_security_group_ids = ["securitygroup-XXXX"]
    },
    read_only = {
      name                   = "read-only-endpoint"
      vpc_subnet_ids         = ["subnet-XXXX"]
      vpc_security_group_ids = ["securitygroup-XXXX"]
      target_role            = "READ_ONLY"
    }
  }
  target_db_cluster     = true
  db_cluster_identifier = "rds-cluster-XXXX"
  ...
}

However, on the deploy step, I get the following error:
│ Error: creating RDS DB Proxy: InvalidSubnet: The subnet ID 'subnet-XXXX' does not exist
│   status code: 400, request id: XXXX
│ 
│   with module.rds-proxy.module.my-rds-proxy.aws_db_proxy.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/rds-proxy.my-rds-proxy/main.tf line 13, in resource "aws_db_proxy" "this":
│   13: resource "aws_db_proxy" "this" {

The subnet subnet-XXXX does in fact exist in us-east-2, and I can go look at it in the console.
The role arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/my-role has a policy that allows access to that subnet:
{
  [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPassRDSProxyRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:PassRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/my-role"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Ec2LimitedResourceAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*VpcEndpoint*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:route-table/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*"
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}

The RDS cluster rds-cluster-XXXX also exists in us-east-2, and I can go view it in the console.
I find it odd that the terraform RDS proxy doesn't allow a provider input. How does it know which region to check for the subnets? Does it assume that it's the same provider as the one specified in the cluster rds-cluster-XXXX that the proxy connects to? Even if that were true, how does it know that the cluster is in us-east-2? Does it check all of the regions for it? I bring this up because creating the proxy in us-east-1 with reference a subnet in us-east-1 works just fine. As soon as I try to do the same in us-east-2, it causes the error indicating that the subnet does not exist.

Usually, for official providers (like aws is) the child module (my-rds-proxy) inherits the settings from the root module, i.e, the place where you are calling the child module from. What you could do is use provider aliases if you need to deploy things in multiple regions.

Thanks for that info. It lead me to the solution, which was to add the following input to the module:
providers = {
aws = aws.secondary_region
}
